# Passar variáveis por rotas

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Ola, estou criando um site em `Laravel` pela primeira vez, e é um site em 3 línguas diferentes. Na `partials`, ele possui o `header`, que tem a opção das 3 línguas, quando eu clico em uma, eu quero passar uma variável dizendo qual língua esta ativa para todo o resto do site. Mas não consegui entender muito bem como fazer.

Aqui é aonde a variável tem que ser enviada.

```
<a href="{{ route('website.index') -> with('lang', $request->lang)}}">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/brazil.png" />
</a>
```

Como fazer ela ser recebida no `index` e demais `views`?

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', 'WebsiteController@index')->name('website.index');

Route::get('header/{lang}', function(Request $resquest){
        return Redirect::route('website.index')->with('id',$id);
    });

 Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/carreira', 'WebsiteController@jobs')->name('website.jobs');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/carreira/{id}', 'WebsiteController@job_open')->name('website.job_open');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/quemsomos', 'WebsiteController@about')->name('website.about');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/consultoria', 'WebsiteController@consulting')->name('website.consulting');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/cursos', 'WebsiteController@courses')->name('website.courses');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/atelie', 'WebsiteController@atelie')->name('website.atelie');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/portfolio/{id}', 'WebsiteController@portfolio')->name('website.portfolio');

Route::post('/contact', 'WebsiteController@contact')->name('website.contact');
```

Comment: posso ver a suas configurações de rota?

Comment: Esta assim por enquanto.

Comment: Você fez a leitura: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#configuring-the-locale as suas rotas estão faltando configurar isso. dá uma olhada! e uma lida, é complicado falar mais do que isso.